# How to use useState with Typescript while passing empty array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to convert my JSX code into typescript (TSX) and having a difficulty in passing the interface while using **useState** hook. All I want is an empty array Interface in my state and on updating i am pushing the object to the Array one by one.

I am getting Typed error on updating the count "Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: IData) => IData'.
Type 'any[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: IData): IData'"

Here is the code i have done:

sample.tsx

```
const interface IData {
id: number
value: string
}
const Sample = () => {

let [count, setCount] = useState<IData>([]);       <------------ Want to know how to pass the blank interface or Array and also how to update interface once values are pushed to the Array

const addCount = () => {
    setCount([...count, {
        id: count.length,
        value: 'Condition ' + count.length      
    }])
}

const handleRemove = (id:number) => {
    console.log(id);
    const count_upd = count.filter((item:any) =>  item.id != id);
    setCount(count_upd);
}


return(
    <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
        { Array(count).fill(<ConditionSeg Data={count.map((item:IData) =>  (
                    item.id,item.value
                ))}
                HandleRemove ={handleRemove}
                />)}
        </Container>
        <Container>
            <Button 
                onClick={addCount}>
                Click me</Button>
        </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

}

P.S. Don't Mind the type errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So as far as I can tell, you want to store an array of values of type `IData`.
In this case you should use

```
let [count, setCount] = useState<IData[]>([]);
```

This means, you are storing an array of values of type `IData`. In your case above you forgot the array brackets, so setCount would actually expect a single object of type `IData` instead of an array.

Comment: ok got it so the interface will be type Array. thanks

Comment: can you also give me some idea on this as well
Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IData[]'.
  Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'IData[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2345)
'ConditionSeg' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key

Comment: So when i am passing this state as props to child i am getting this error stating Element is not assignable to parameter of type IData[]

Comment: **Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IData[]' ...**: This means you use a value of type 'Element' somewhere in your code where a value of type 'IData[]' is expected. The 'Element' type is what is produced by react components.

Comment: **'ConditionSeg' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element.**: This means you return an array in 'ConditionSeg', but that is not valid. You should always return single elements of type 'Element'.